# Uploading jar to maven artifactory on war project

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi-project gradle build. One of the child projects called project2 uses the war plugin. I want this child project to generate a both a war and a jar, but I would upload only the jar file to a maven artifactory. I did the following in the parent build.gradle file:

```
//project2 has REST API and produces a war
def uploadables = [project(':project1'), project(':project2')]
configure(uploadables) {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    uploadArchives {
       repositories.mavenDeployer {
          repository(id: 'repoid', url: 'http://myartifactory') {
            authentication(userName: 'mavenuser', password: 'secret')
          }

       }
    }
}
```

This rightfully produces a project1 jar and a project2 war and uploads project1 jar. However this also uploads project2 war which is something I don't want. I know I can make gradle generate a jar for project2 by adding the jar task to the gradle command line, but how do I tell gradle to upload project2 jar to the artifactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not RTFM. Answer is here http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:multiple_artifacts_per_project

Comment: posting just a link is not an answer!